# Best way to trigger a script for any change in one of several properties

Tags: qt, qml

When you bind a property it will be reevaluated if one of the proprieties to which is bounded is changed.
Example:

```
property bool test: prCond1 || prCond2 || ... || prCondN
```

When a condition is changed `test` is reevaluated.

Now... I want something similar but for triggering a javascript function:
when one of several conditions `prCond1 || prCond2 || ... || prCondN` is changed I want a function to be called.

If there was only one condition I could write:

```
onPrCond1Changed: {
    functionCall()
}
```

But when you take into account more than one condition what is the best way to do it? Is there a standard way?

Basically I need something like this:

```
functionCall() if one of these changes: prCond1 || prCond2 || ... || prCondN
```

Where prCond's may be of different types.

Comment: are the prCond1-prCondN predefined properties/variables, or are they inline-evaluated statements? If the only thing that matters is if property test is changed, then onTestChanged() would be sufficient.

Comment: prCond1-prCondN are predefined properties of different types(which may be strings, ints and bools) which are bound to some Q_PROPERTY's from C++.

The test property example was only an example of the capabilities of Qt to change the value of a property when any property changes from a bunch of others, I asked if there is something similar(when you have bunch of properties) but for triggering a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to group the variables into a variant list and look for changes on the list.

```
property var myObject = {'prop': 'value'}
property variant conditions = [prCond1, prCond2, myObj]

onConditionsChanged: {
   console.log("one of the conditions have changed");
}
```

Note that changes in the properties of myObj will not trigger the changeEvent, unless the object itself is changed (e.g. myObj = new Object({'prop': 'newValue'}) )

Comment: This is the simplest I guess, but I thought there may be a more elegant way.